# Drawing a RNN scheme

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-styles

[image]

Can someone please help me do this scheme in latex? Is it possible?

So far I tried this:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, bending, chains, graphs, positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    % First figure: Time stamp = 1.0
    \begin{minipage}{.32\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[nn width/.initial=.75cm,
  every nn layer label/.style={
    node font=\footnotesize, label position=above, anchor=north,
    inner xsep=+.15em, align=center,
    text width={max(width("Output"),\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/nn width}}},
  every nn node/.style={
    shape=circle, draw, solid,
    minimum size=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/nn width}},
  every nn layer/.style={draw, node distance=1.25em}, % distance between circles
  nn layer/.style args={#1:#2}{
    matrix, every nn layer,
    execute at empty cell={
      \tikzset{new set=\tikzmatrixname,
        start chain={\tikzmatrixname} going below}%
      \node foreach \nncount in {1, ..., #1}[%
        on chain, set=\tikzmatrixname, every nn node, nn node \nncount/.try]{};
      \node[every nn layer label, above=1em of \tikzmatrixname-begin]{#2};},
    node contents=\\},
  nn layer'/.style={densely dashed, nn layer={#1}}][
  >={Latex[round, scale=.7]},
  every curve to/.style={distance=7mm},
  dd/.style=densely dotted,
  node distance=.5em and 1cm, % this controls the distance between layers
]
\node (inp) [                          nn layer'=2:Input  Layer];
\node (buf) [below=of inp,             nn layer =3:Buffer      ];
\node (hid) [right=of buf, yshift=3em, nn layer'=3:Hidden Layer];
\node (out) [right=of hid,             nn layer'=1:Output Layer];

\graph {
  {(inp), (buf)} ->[complete bipartite,     out=  0, in=180] (hid)
                 ->[complete bipartite, dd                 ] (out),
  (hid)          ->[                    dd, out=-90, in= 90] (buf)
};

% Time stamp label below the buffer
\node[below=of buf, label distance=2em] {Time stamp = 1.0};

            % (Include your complete TikZ code for the first figure here)
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    % Second figure: Time stamp = 1.5
    \begin{minipage}{.32\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[nn width/.initial=.75cm,
  every nn layer label/.style={
    node font=\footnotesize, label position=above, anchor=north,
    inner xsep=+.15em, align=center,
    text width={max(width("Output"),\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/nn width})}},
  every nn node/.style={
    shape=circle, draw, solid,
    minimum size=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/nn width}},
  every nn layer/.style={draw, node distance=1.25em}, % distance between circles
  nn layer/.style args={#1:#2}{
    matrix, every nn layer,
    execute at empty cell={
      \tikzset{new set=\tikzmatrixname,
        start chain={\tikzmatrixname} going below}%
      \node foreach \nncount in {1, ..., #1}[%
        on chain, set=\tikzmatrixname, every nn node, nn node \nncount/.try]{};
      \node[every nn layer label, above=1em of \tikzmatrixname-begin]{#2};},
    node contents=\\},
  nn layer'/.style={densely dashed, nn layer={#1}}][
  >={Latex[round, scale=.7]},
  every curve to/.style={distance=7mm},
  dd/.style=densely dashed,
  node distance=.5em and 1cm, % this controls the distance between layers
]
\node (inp) [                          nn layer'=2:Input  Layer];
\node (buf) [below=of inp,             nn layer =3:Buffer      ];
\node (hid) [right=of buf, yshift=3em, nn layer'=3:Hidden Layer];
\node (out) [right=of hid,             nn layer'=1:Output Layer];

\graph {
  {(inp), (buf)} ->[complete bipartite, dd, out=  0, in=180] (hid)
                 ->[complete bipartite,                      ] (out),
  (hid)          ->[                    out=-90, in= 90] (buf)
};

% Time stamp label below the buffer
\node[below=of buf, label distance=2em] {Time stamp = 1.5};

            % (Include your complete TikZ code for the second figure here)
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    % Third figure: Time stamp = 2.0
    \begin{minipage}{.32\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[nn width/.initial=.75cm,
  every nn layer label/.style={
    node font=\footnotesize, label position=above, anchor=north,
    inner xsep=+.15em, align=center,
    text width={max(width("Output"),\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/nn width}}},
  every nn node/.style={
    shape=circle, draw, solid,
    minimum size=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/nn width}},
  every nn layer/.style={draw, node distance=1.25em}, % distance between circles
  nn layer/.style args={#1:#2}{
    matrix, every nn layer,
    execute at empty cell={
      \tikzset{new set=\tikzmatrixname,
        start chain={\tikzmatrixname} going below}%
      \node foreach \nncount in {1, ..., #1}[%
        on chain, set=\tikzmatrixname, every nn node, nn node \nncount/.try]{};
      \node[every nn layer label, above=1em of \tikzmatrixname-begin]{#2};},
    node contents=\\},
  nn layer'/.style={densely dashed, nn layer={#1}}][
  >={Latex[round, scale=.7]},
  every curve to/.style={distance=7mm},
  dd/.style=densely dotted,
  node distance=.5em and 1cm, % this controls the distance between layers
]
\node (inp) [                          nn layer'=2:Input  Layer];
\node (buf) [below=of inp,             nn layer =3:Buffer      ];
\node (hid) [right=of buf, yshift=3em, nn layer'=3:Hidden Layer];
\node (out) [right=of hid,             nn layer'=1:Output Layer];

\graph {
  {(inp), (buf)} ->[complete bipartite,     out=  0, in=180] (hid)
                 ->[complete bipartite, dd                 ] (out),
  (hid)          ->[                    dd, out=-90, in= 90] (buf)
};
a
% Time stamp label below the buffer
\node[below=of buf, label distance=2em] {Time stamp = 1.0};

            % (Include your complete TikZ code for the third figure here)
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{RNN at different time stamps.}
    \label{fig:rnn_time_stamps}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

But I got an awful result putting these together:
[image]

I'm really new to this

Comment: Plenty of similar kinds of things already on the site: https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=Neural+network

Comment: Hi, thank you! But I tried to find an RNN similar to this one and I can't find anything like this

Comment: Please show what you tried so far. Post some code clarify where exactly your problem is.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. Since it gives an error, the result is only an aid to debugging. You are trying to reference `input3` but you only made `input1` and `input2`.

Answer (score 7):

Inspired by my own answers for [drawing neural networks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=Neural%20network%20user%3A16595) each layer is a matrix with only one cell,
the nodes inside a layer are placed on a chain,
the nodes are connected via the `graphs` library's syntax
since it makes it much easier to connect a bunch of nodes.

For this, each matrix sets up a set named after the matrix and each node inside a matrix is put into this set. Inside the `graph` operation all nodes of a set can be referenced by using its name in parentheses (as if it were one node).

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, bending, chains, graphs, positioning}
\tikzset{
  nn width/.initial=.75cm,
  every nn layer label/.style={
    node font=\footnotesize, label position=above, anchor=north,
    inner xsep=+.15em, align=center,
    text width={max(width("Output"),\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/nn width}}},
  every nn node/.style={
    shape=circle, draw, solid,
    minimum size=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/nn width}},
  every nn layer/.style={draw, node distance=1.25em}, % distance between circles
  nn layer/.style args={#1:#2}{
    matrix, every nn layer,
    execute at empty cell={
      \tikzset{new set=\tikzmatrixname,
        start chain={\tikzmatrixname} going below}%
      \node foreach \nncount in {1, ..., #1}[%
        on chain, set=\tikzmatrixname, every nn node, nn node \nncount/.try]{};
      \node[every nn layer label, above=1em of \tikzmatrixname-begin]{#2};},
    node contents=\\},
  nn layer'/.style={densely dashed, nn layer={#1}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  >={Latex[round, scale=.7]},
  every curve to/.style={distance=7mm},
  dd/.style=densely dotted,
  node distance=.5em and 1cm, % this controls the distance between layers
]
\node (inp) [                          nn layer'=2:Input  Layer];
\node (buf) [below=of inp,             nn layer =3:Buffer      ];
\node (hid) [right=of buf, yshift=3em, nn layer'=3:Hidden Layer];
\node (out) [right=of hid,             nn layer'=1:Output Layer];

\graph {
  {(inp), (buf)} ->[complete bipartite,     out=  0, in=180] (hid)
                 ->[complete bipartite, dd                 ] (out),
  (hid)          ->[                    dd, out=-90, in= 90] (buf)
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You could, for example, use a `matrix of nodes` to layout the basics and the `fit` library to draw the perimeters of the layers. The `bending` library can help with arrows on curves and `arrows.meta` provides a choice of arrow tips.

The following example demonstrates two methods of drawing curves. (There are many more!)

[image: sample diagram]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,fit,arrows.meta,bending}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/701679/ i gwestiwn bdzh: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/701674/
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    nnode/.style={draw,rounded corners,text width=10mm,text height=10mm,anchor=south},
    lnode/.style={text width=10mm,align=center,anchor=south,inner sep=0pt},
    lfit/.style={draw,dashed,fit=#1},
  ]
  \matrix (mat) [matrix of nodes,nodes in empty cells,row sep=5mm,column sep=20mm]
  {
    |[lnode]| {Input\\Layer} & &  \\
    |[nnode]| & &  \\
    |[nnode]| &  |[lnode]| {Hidden\\Layer} &  \\
    |[lnode]| Buffer  &  |[nnode]| & |[lnode]| {Output\\Layer} \\
    |[nnode]|  & |[nnode]| &  |[nnode]| \\
    |[nnode]|  & |[nnode]| &  \\
    |[nnode]|  & &  \\    
   };
   \node (ol) [lfit=(mat-4-3) (mat-5-3)] {};
   \node (hl) [lfit=(mat-3-2) (mat-4-2) (mat-5-2) (mat-6-2)] {};
   \node (il) [lfit=(mat-1-1) (mat-2-1) (mat-3-1)] {};
   \node (bf) [lfit=(mat-4-1) (mat-5-1) (mat-6-1) (mat-7-1), solid] {};
   \foreach \i/\k/\m in {2/0/120,3/0/140,5/0/180,6/0/200,7/0/235}
    \foreach \j in {4,5,6}
      \draw [-{Latex[bend]}] (mat-\i-1) [out=\k,in=\m] to (mat-\j-2.west);
   \foreach \i in {4,5,6} \draw [-{Latex},dashed] (mat-\i-2.0) -- (mat-5-3.west);
   \foreach \i/\j in {4/5,5/6,6/7} \draw [-{Latex[bend]},dashed] (mat-\i-2.south) .. controls +(-1,-1) and +(1,1) .. (mat-\j-1.north);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```